# Market Basket analysis -Apriori Algorithm Database Sample (Ms Sql Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sample-data

i'm looking a database sample for Apriori Algorithm. i need to find e-commerce site's database or a supermarket database. it's for my school homework. Can you advice me something?

note: sorry my bad english.

Comment: The classic SQL Server example database is [Northwind](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06616212-0356-46a0-8da2-eebc53a68034&displaylang=en).  I suppose most e-commerce sites and supermarkets don't share their data, but perhaps there's one that does!

Answer (score 0):

I think the latest microsoft one is AdventureWorks and you can download it from codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL server from Microsoft there is a database named FoodMart 2000 that contains a sample database for a supermarket.

It was included in SQL Server 2000 and should also be included in more recent versions.